# What is it called when you Build Up One Class out of Other Classes?

Tags: c#, class

I am learning C# quite recently and understand the basics. I am not writing this code below but trying to understand it. The line class uses Point when declaring the start and end fields. What is this called in C#?

```
public class Point
{
    private float x;

    public float X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
    private float y;

    public float Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set { y = value; }
    }

    public Point(float x, float y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point():this(0,0)
    {
    }

   }

}

class Line
{
    private Point start;

    public Point Start
    {
      get { return start; }
      set { start = value; }
    }

    private Point end;

    public Point End
    {
      get { return end; }
      set { end = value; }
    }

    public Line(Point start, Point end)
    {
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    public Line():this(new Point(), new Point())
    {
    }
```

Comment: A field which is directly linked to a property in the way you use it? *Properties with backing fields*.

Comment: Shano, there are plenty of awesome Tutorials online that can explain Classes,Structs,Properties and Fields start with the basic ones and work your way up to the more complex examples that can be found here http://www.dotnetperls.com/class or on http://www.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

I’m unsure what you are asking, but I think you want to know the correct terminology:

```
public class Point // a class (obviously)
{
    private float x; // private field; also the backing
                     // field for the property `X`

    public float X // a public property
    {
        get { return x; }  // (public) getter of the property
        set { x = value; } // (public) setter of the property
                           // both are using the backing field
    }


    public float Y // an auto-implemented property (this one will
    { get; set; }  // create the backing field, the getter and the
                   // automatically, but hide it from accessing it directly)

    public Point(float x, float y) // constructor
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public Point()  // a default constructor that calls another by
        : this(0,0) // using an "instance constructor initializer"
    {}
}
```

Comment: Nice summary. I've fixed a couple of small errors and added that the invocation of the second constructor is called an "instance constructor initializer".

Comment: Cheers guys for your help but I think I discovered what was confusing me. I did not word my question very well!! Problem I have is in the Line Class where it uses the Point Class to declare the fields and in the constructor. Its called Composition I believe and differs from Inheritance as its a has a relationship. I will do some more research on it now :) Thanks again!